# Prove $\lim_{n\to \infty} P(n^{1/2} \cdot (\bar{x} - 1 ) < t) = P(Z < t) $ ($X$ exponential)

Tags: probability, probability-theory, convergence-divergence

$x_{i}$, $i = 1, 2, 3, \dots$ i.i.d. from exponential ($\lambda = 1$) $Z$-standard normal r.v.

$$ \lim_{n\to \infty} P(n^{1/2} \cdot (\bar{x} - 1 ) < t) = P(Z < t) $$

It seems like I could somehow apply CLT, but I may be wrong. I tried to rearrange the equation, but I'm not sure how to treat $P(n^{1/2} \cdot (\bar{x} - 1 ) < t)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The central limit theorem is all you need here.  The expected value and the standard deviation are both $1$.  Just plug everything into the CLT and you've got it.

Comment: this makes perfect sense. I don't know what I was thinking about. The only part that I don't understand is "less" sign as opposed to "less or equals" in CLT ( "<t" )

Comment: The difference between $<$ and $\le$ matters only when the distribution is at least partly discrete, not if it's entirely continuous.